# ReactJS Material UI aligning form field center

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am going through a trouble to align my react form to center.

This is my form:

I am using reactjs Material UI

```
 <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>

            <FormGroup noValidate autoComplete="on">
              <TextField
                label="SSN"
                type="number"
                className={classes.textField}
                name='ssn'
              />
            </FormGroup>

          </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

i am trying to align the form to center.

If you want to see entire component, this is the component that contain the form

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import useStyles from '../src/styleMaker'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { FormGroup } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


function App(props) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    container: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    textField: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200,
    },
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();


  return (

    <React.Fragment>
    <div className={classes.container}>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>

            <FormGroup noValidate autoComplete="on">
              <TextField
                label="SSN"
                type="number"
                className={classes.textField}
                name='ssn'
              />
            </FormGroup>

          </Grid>
      </Grid>

    </div>

    </React.Fragment>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone help me to make this form to center? I tried whole day long but i failed to align.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you use to make form centered horizontally, add following style to `makeStyles`

   ```
   formGroup: {
     alignItems: 'center'
   }
   ```

   and assign `formGroup` class name to `<FormGroup>`

   ```
   <FormGroup className={classes.formGroup} noValidate autoComplete="on">
       <TextField
           label="SSN"
           type="number"
           className={classes.textField}
           name='ssn'
       />
   </FormGroup>
   ```

   Here is [working form](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-horizontal-center-ln3y7)
2. If you want to center it vertically and horizontally, the easiest way is to make some root `<div>` positioned absolutely and set `width` and `height` to `100%`. This makes `<div>` to occupy whole screen. Then you can use `justify-content` and `align-items` to center form.

   ```
   container: {
     display: "flex",
     flexWrap: "wrap",
     position: "absolute",
     top: 0,
     left: 0,
     height: "100%",
     width: "100%",
     alignItems: "center"
   },
   ```

   Here is [working form](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-center-vertandhorizont-s5mo1), that is aligned to center both horizontally and vertically